# Qt variable lifetime misunderstanding

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following working code:

```
QFile file(fileName);
if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) throw GException(GString("Failed to open file "));
QTextStream stream(&file);

QString s = stream.readAll();
QByteArray source = s.toUtf8();
const char *string = source.data();
glShaderSource(id, 1, &string, NULL);
glCompileShader(id);
qDebug() << QString(string);
```

If I remove `QString` variable like this, the code continues to work:

```
QByteArray source = stream.readAll().toUtf8();
const char *string = source.data();
glShaderSource(id, 1, &string, NULL);
glCompileShader(id);
qDebug() << QString(string);
```

But removing `QByteArray` causes string to point to garbage:

```
QString s = stream.readAll();
const char *string = s.toUtf8().data();
glShaderSource(id, 1, &string, NULL);
glCompileShader(id);
qDebug() << QString(string); // GARBAGE HERE
```

I cannot find information related to this behaviour in the documentation here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toUtf8

I guess that `toUtf8()` method doesn't return pointer to the internal array but creates a new one.

I am new to Qt and since I'm missing this in the documentation, I have no idea how to avoid similar issues in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QString::toUtf8()` returns a `QByteArray`, not a pointer. [`QString`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#details) doesn't store the string as an utf-8 C string :

> QString stores a string of 16-bit QChars, where each QChar corresponds
>   one Unicode 4.0 character. (Unicode characters with code values above
>   65535 are stored using surrogate pairs, i.e., two consecutive QChars.)

On that line :

```
const char *string = s.toUtf8().data();
```

You are using [`QByteArray::data()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#data) on a temporary `QByteArray`, but as the documentation of `data()` says :

> The pointer remains valid as long as the byte array isn't reallocated
>   or destroyed.

Comment: I get that, thanks a lot. When I said 'pointer', I didn't mean that QByteArray is a pointer but that it contains a pointer to the array inside. Anyway, now I see the root cause. `toUtf8()` performs conversion as internal encoding is not UTF-8. I didn't think about it.